# Error on a fortran constructor

Tags: oop, constructor, fortran

I want to extend an abstract type and then initialize with a constructor but I got the error (from gfortran)
"Error: No initializer for component 'feature' given in the structure constructor  !"
 The first module is

```
module A_Module
 implicit none
 type A
    double precision :: x,y
 end  type A
contains
end module A_Module
```

The second module is

```
module B_module
use A_Module
type, abstract :: B
    contains
    procedure (Compute_BFeature), deferred :: B_Feat
end type B
abstract interface
    function Compute_BFeature(this)
        import B
        double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: Compute_BFeature
        class (B)::this
    end function Compute_BFeature
end interface
type, extends(B) :: B_new
    type (A), dimension(2) :: A_list
    double precision, dimension(2) :: Feature
  contains
    procedure :: B_Feat => B_new_Feature
end type B_new

interface B_new
    procedure B_new_Constructor
end interface

contains

function B_new_Constructor(this,A_listInput)
    type(B_new):: B_new_Constructor
    type (A), dimension(2), intent(in) :: A_listInput
      B_new_Constructor%A_list = A_listInput
   B_new_Constructor%Feature = B_new_Constructor%B_Feat()
end function

function B_new_Feature (this)
    double precision, dimension(:) ,  allocatable :: B_new_Feature
    class (B_new) :: this
    allocate(B_new_Feature(2))
    B_new_Feature(1) = -(this%A_list(2)%y - this%A_list(1)%y)
    B_new_Feature(2) = this%A_list(2)%x - this%A_list(1)%x
end function
end module B_module
```

Instead of

```
    B_new_Constructor%Feature = B_new_Constructor%B_Feat()
```

I tried using also

```
    B_new_Constructor%Feature(1) = 1.0
    B_new_Constructor%Feature(2) = 1.0
```

but gfortran always returns the same error.
In order to understand wheter the problem is with my B_new_Feature function
I tried to see if the error is with the allocatable statement of the function but, even having Feature as a double precision scalar (and B_new_Feature adjusted accordignly) the compiler still complains the same way.
At this moment after many trials, I cannot find what is the error, any idea?

Comment: 4.7 and above (I work with ming 64 on win 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Because I am still new to Fortran OOP features, the following Answer may contain some big errors, so pls be careful... Tested with gfortran4.8.2)

First in `B_new_Constructor()`, `this` is given as the first argument but not declared explicitly (probably a typo). Because there is no `implicit none`, no error occurs with this implicit `this`. Also, as far as I understand, Fortran's "constructor" is not a member function of derived type but often refers to a module procedure that is overloaded with the default structure constructor for returning a new object. So there is no need to pass `this` to the user-defined constructor (here, `B_new_Constructor()`) but rather it is expected to return a newly constructed object.

With the original code, a main program like this

```
program main
    use B_module, only: A, B_new
    type(B_new) :: p, q, r

    p = B_new()
    print *, "p = ", p

    q = B_new( [ A(1.0d0,2.0d0), A(3.0d0,4.0d0) ] )
    print *, "q = ", q

    r = B_new( [ A(1.0d0,2.0d0), A(3.0d0,4.0d0) ], [ 5.0d0, 6.0d0 ] )
    print *, "r = ", r
end
```

gives an error message like

```
p = B_new()
    1
Error: No initializer for component 'a_list' given in the structure constructor at (1)!

q = B_new( [ A(1.0d0,2.0d0), A(3.0d0,4.0d0) ] )
    1
Error: No initializer for component 'feature' given in the structure constructor at (1)!
```

Now if we  attach `implicit none` at the top of `B_module` and change `B_new_Constructor()` as

```
function B_new_Constructor( A_listInput ) result( ret )
    type(A)     :: A_listInput( 2 )
    type(B_new) :: ret

    print *, "modified constructor called (no optional)"
    ret% A_list(:)  = A_listInput(:)
    ret% Feature(:) = ret% B_Feat()
endfunction
```

we still get the same error for `p`

```
p = B_new()
    1
Error: No initializer for component 'a_list' given in the structure constructor at (1)!
```

This is probably because there is no matching procedure for a call with no argument (here we assume that the default structure constructor requires two arguments). One method to deal with this may be to use `optional` keywords like

```
function B_new_Constructor( A_listInput , featInput ) result( ret )
    type(A),          optional :: A_listInput( 2 )
    double precision, optional :: featInput( 2 )
    type(B_new)                :: ret

    print *, "modified constructor called"
    if ( present( A_listInput ) ) ret% A_list(:) = A_listInput(:)
    if ( present( featInput ) ) then
        ret% Feature(:) = featInput(:)
    else
        ret% Feature(:) = ret% B_Feat()
    endif
endfunction
```

Then the program runs as

```
modified constructor called
p =   1.24543954074099760E-312  1.24546058728534379E-312  1.24543953672918456E-312 2.12199579096527232E-314  1.22424062937569107E-312 -4.01181304423092194E-321
modified constructor called
q =    1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   -2.0  2.0   !! format slightly changed to fit the terminal
modified constructor called
r =    1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0    5.0  6.0
```

This output shows that given two arguments, the user-defined constructor has precedence over the default structure constructor.

To avoid `optional` keywords, we can also use default initializers such that

```
type A
    double precision :: x = 100.0d0, y = 200.0d0
endtype

type, extends(B) :: B_new
    type(A)          :: A_list(2)
    double precision :: Feature(2) = [ 300.0d0, 400.0d0 ]
contains
    ...
endtype
```

then the first modified version of `B_new_Constructor()` (with no `optional`) works as well

```
p =    100.0  200.0  100.0  200.0  300.0  400.0
modified constructor called (no optional)
q =    1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  -2.0  2.0
r =    1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   5.0  6.0
```

This output shows that the default structure constructor is called at least for `r`.

### ----------

EDIT: If we want to allow only the one-argument constructor (here, `A_listInput`), there may be two approaches. One is to modify the above `B_new_Constructor()` with two optional arguments by including the following to prohibit other cases:

```
if ( (        present( A_listInput )  .and.        present( featInput )  ) .or. &
     ( (.not. present( A_listInput )) .and. (.not. present( featInput )) )  ) then
    stop "only one arg permitted"
endif
```

and the other approach is to define constructors with no argument or two argument as a "dummy":

```
function B_new_Constructor_arg1 ( A_listInput ) result( ret )
    type(A)     :: A_listInput( 2 )
    type(B_new) :: ret

    ret% A_list(:)  = A_listInput(:)
    ret% Feature(:) = ret% B_Feat()
endfunction

function B_new_Constructor_arg0 () result( ret )
    type(B_new) :: ret
    stop "constructor with no argument prohibited"
endfunction

function B_new_Constructor_arg2 ( A_listInput, featInput ) result( ret )
    type(A)          :: A_listInput( 2 )
    double precision :: featInput( 2 )
    type(B_new) :: ret
    stop "constructor with two arguments prohibited"
endfunction
```

with

```
interface B_new
    procedure B_new_Constructor_arg1
    procedure B_new_Constructor_arg0  !! this masks default initializers (if any)
    procedure B_new_Constructor_arg2  !! this masks default structure constructor
endinterface
```

Both approaches seem to work, but both are not very elegant... (hopefully there will be a better way to do this). [And I am sorry to be too long for a single Answer.]

Comment: Indeed returning an error for p = B_new() is not bad. I would like to have B_new called only with the A_listInput. Feature is a value that should be computed from A_listInput and stored in the object only for convenience (it could be recomputed every time). I appreciate the use of optional. Regarding its use I have to check better (anyway the implicit none just slipped out of my keyboard)

Comment: Most probably I could add a flag to check if the Feature has been initialized or not. In this way I could skip the `optional` and prevent anybody from using the constructor form the way I want

Comment: @ray I added two approaches in the Edit for allowing only one-argument constructor, but they are far from elegant... I hope someone more familiar with this stuff will show a more cool approach :) (Btw I also wish a more convenient way to check the status of member variables....)

Comment: Nobody showed up with a better solution, so I used yours (and of course is working) and I ticked it to thank you for your time. Still I am a bit unconfortable with the fact the I have to declare a defalut. It does not look the safest way of doing this, nevertheless thank you